# XPE and XPAnalyzer ISE calculates voltage and current based on what models?

Tags: models, xilinx-ise

Maybe a noob question but, I would like to know how XPA and XPE ISE calculate power, voltages or curent. I mean, I undestand all about pre or post implemenatation stuff and what's the differnce between those tools(and the results they give) , but those results are based on what models?

Thanks!